# Doesn't get value with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<form method="POST">
<div id="showme">Show me <?php echo $_POST['name']?></div>
Send the value<input type="radio" name="name" value="ja"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="BEREKENEN! ">
</form>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showme').hide();
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#showme').fadeIn(5000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

This code won't send the value of the radiobutton to the `showme` div.
I can't receive the `$_POST['name']` when I use `hide()` and `fadeIn()` between the `<script>` tags.

Whenever I don't use jQuery it sends the data - when using it , it won't let me send the value.
How do I fix this problem, this is just an example of 1 radio button. I have a list of 6 radiobuttons that need to be sent to PHP section in the same file, I don't want to make another file for this.

This code will FadeIn the requested div, it shows me `Show me` but it won't show the value where I ask for with the line `<?php echo $_POST['name']?>`

Comment: Your `e.preventDefault();` line tells the form not to submit, so PHP never sees your value in order to display it. If you want to submit without the page refreshing, you'll need to POST the value to your PHP server using AJAX. If you don't need the server to see the value, just get the value using `$('input:radio[name=name]:checked').val()` and display it using `$('#showme').html('.... that value...')`

Comment: Why not do something like:
http://jsfiddle.net/mRqN2/

Comment: @Shai can you JSFIDDLE that one i didnt get it right.

Comment: @TomHeard, thats sort of what i want, but what if i set more radiobuttons. How to show ifs checked ?

Comment: @user3104720 Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/shai/mRqN2/5/ – this is the solution assuming you don't have to send your value to the PHP server for any reason

Answer (score 1):

PHP is parsed on the server.  `<?php echo $_POST['name']?>` has already been evaluated and `echo`d to the page long before any of the submission stuff happens.  What you need is to use AJAX.

You can replace the `submit` button with just a regular button, remove the `<form>` element entirely even.

### jQuery:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('page.php', { name: $('input[name="name"]').val() }, function ( data ) {
        $('#showme').append(data).fadeIn(5000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

*(if you do what I did below turning `submit` into `button`, you dont need the `e.preventDefault()`)*

### PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) { 
    echo $_POST['name'];
    return;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="showme">Show me </div>
<label for="name">Send the value</label><input type="radio" name="name" value="ja"/>
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="BEREKENEN!">
```

I'm not so sure you can get a non-BOOLEAN value from a radio button with PHP though.  You're probably better off using `<input type="hidden" value="ja" />` or maybe `type="text"`.